# NOLOCK vs Read Uncommitted

Tags: sql-server, replication, deadlock, isolation-level

in our environment, reports are running on the subscriber and resulting in deadlocks with MS Replication SPs, which are doing inserts/updates. What's the best way to eliminate the deadlocks?

We have several views with so many dependencies without `NOLOCK`.

What is the best option:

- Updating all the views with `NOLOCK`

  or
- Using the `READ UNCOMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL`

Or some other best option?

Our requirement is reading the current data from subscriber (with no latency from publisher). We are OK with some dirty reads. Looking for best approach before updating so many views.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using snapshot or read committed snapshot isolations?

Comment: just an FYI, replication does not support "no latency from publisher".  Replication is asynchronous operation, thus you will always have latency between the publisher and subscriber.